# Estimating covariance matrix from multiple distance measurements

Tags: variance, nonlinear-regression

I have a setup that can measure the distance between two *beacons*. The first beacon is aware of its 2D location and is moving around while measuring the distance to the second beacon. I've setup a system of equations that I solve using non-linear optimization. I optimize for $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$, i.e. the position of the second beacon, the error in the distance measurement ($r$):
$$ \mathrm{error} = e_i =  \sqrt{(x_i-\bar{x})^2 + (y_i-\bar{y})^2} - r_i $$
The algorithm optimizes the squared error in the distance.
$$ \mathrm{cost} = \sum_{i=1}^N e_i^2 $$
In this manner I have found the location of the second beacon.

The averaged residual gives me some indication of the certainty with which I know the location of the second beacon.
The certainty of my estimation is still unclear however and I would like to estimate this. How can I go about determining the covariance matrix, $\Sigma$?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40660 for one solution.